# 2D array indexed with 2 variable to 1d array

Tags: python, arrays

I have saved an 2D array something like this:-

```
Cell["a","b"]=[1,2,3]
Cell["a","c"]=[4,5,6]
Cell["b","c"]=[7,8,9]
```

I want to fetch out all the entries which are `Cell["a", anyvalue]` without going through the whole list.
What will be the best way of doing this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it. I am using Python

Comment: Do you mean dictionary?